# Where would be web_sockets equivalent in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, windows, websocket, wamp

The thing is I have here a group of web developers and everyone works with WAMP in Windows. In there they work with a php extension called `php_websockets`. Basically in `php.ini` they just uncomment `;php_websockets.dll` and voila.

On the other hand I work with Linux *(CentOS 7 in this case)*, and there's no possible way I can find `php_websockets` in any `php.ini` or conf archives.

I know there are a lot of web sockets out there. But they insist me it **must** be this one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are multiple "php websockets" projects out there; finding out the version number of the one they are using might help.  Assuming it's this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwebsockets/, there are linux installation instructions at http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwebsockets/files/:

> LINUX INSTALLATION - Tested and works on the following systems:
>   - Fedora Core 17 PHP-5.4.9 x86_64
>   - Fedora Core 18 PHP-5.4.10 x86_64
>   - Fedora Core 18 PHP-5.4.12 x86_64
>
> Build it from source - Simply unpack the files and at a shell prompt type these commands.

```
# phpize
# ./configure --enable-websockets
# make
# make install
# cp websockets.ini /etc/php.d/
```

> If all went smoothly, websockets should be installed and working.
>   If you have any issues, please post them in the sourceforge ticket system
>   https://sourceforge.net/p/phpwebsockets/tickets/
>
> NOTE: You will have to re-build if you update PHP